# starting tomcat via startup.sh fails with sudo -u myuser while running shell as user works

Tags: java, openjdk, tomcat, tomcat6

```
sudo -u myuser sh /var/lib/tomcat6/bin/startup.sh
```

fails while

```
sh /var/lib/tomcat6/bin/startup.sh
```

as user myuser works

I try to run it as root user to start a service:

errors:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java: 1: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java: ▒▒: not found
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java: 1: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java: ▒▒: not found
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java: 1: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java: ▒▒: not found
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java: 1: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java: cannot create 1@@8▒@8: Permission denied
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java: 1: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java:ELF: not found
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java: 2: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```